# Magento Create Product with C# not passing data

Tags: c#, magento, magento-1.8

I have gone through the entire stackoverflow and Google samples for a working piece of code, but cannot get this to work:

```
static bool createProduct(string prodName, string prodDesc, string prodShort, string prodPrice, string prodSku)
{

    catalogProductCreateEntity newProduct = new catalogProductCreateEntity();
    newProduct.name = prodName;
    newProduct.description = prodDesc;
    newProduct.short_description = prodShort;
    newProduct.status = "1";
    newProduct.price = prodPrice;
    newProduct.tax_class_id = "2";
    newProduct.weight = "1";           

    string defaultAttrubiteSetID = "4";

    associativeEntity AdditionalAttributes = new associativeEntity();
    AdditionalAttributes.key = "temando_height";
    AdditionalAttributes.value = "0.2";
    associativeEntity[] AssociativeEntity = new associativeEntity[2];
    AssociativeEntity[0] = AdditionalAttributes;
    newProduct.additional_attributes = AssociativeEntity;

    AdditionalAttributes = new associativeEntity();
    AdditionalAttributes.key = "temando_width";
    AdditionalAttributes.value = "0.1";
    AssociativeEntity[1] = AdditionalAttributes;
    newProduct.additional_attributes = AssociativeEntity;

    try
    {

        mservice.catalogProductCreate(mlogin, "simple", defaultAttrubiteSetID , prodSku, newProduct, null);
    }
    catch (Exception merror)
    {
        lastError = merror.Message;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have tried "temandoHeight" and "temandoheight" variations, but none of them works with Magento 1.8

The product gets created without any problems, but none of the additional 2 additional attributes mentioned above that I tried will get populated.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try 
    newProduct.additional_attributes.single_data = AssociativeEntity;

That is what I have to do with python when using the API

Comment: the single_data option does not seem to be available as described, but I do remember seeing it somewhere... I will poke around...

Comment: The problem: SOAPv2 with WS-I does not use the single_data and multi_data attributes. Therefore the check in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php in _prepareDataForSave fails....

Comment: Ah I don't know what would be causing it with WS-I turned on. As a workaround can you fetch the product data with the additional attributes you need, resave the additional attributes then save it back up to the api? 

It could be something as daft as the store id not being set knowing magento

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the set up for "temando_height" and "temando_width" attributes, there may be something you need to change in the settings of the attribute. Just a regular check.

Also, did you tried sending different values like more than 1, normally shipping modules they don't accept values less than 1cm.